# String request with volley fail

Tags: android, android-volley

Good day, String request with volley fail error  //-- Unexpected response code 404 for https://www.express.pk/world/archives/?page=1  --//

```
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest
            ("https://www.express.pk/world/archives/?page=1", new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.d("check", "ok");
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    neonews();
                    Log.d("check", "fail");
                }
            });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: I am getting the error on Android Q, but this works on Android O(reo).  Are you running on Android Q, by chance?

Answer (score 0):

add request method GET or POST 
replace your

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest
        ("https://www.express.pk/world/archives/?page=1", new Response.Listener<String>()
```

with

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest
        (Request.Method.GET,"https://www.express.pk/world/archives/?page=1", new Response.Listener<String>()
```

If you are not getting success response and it goes to Error Response 
check whether API have any parameter that will pass on API call

Answer (score 0):

Using volley you should define specific http request type(`GET, POST, PUT, DELETE`).

[Official doc give a good example](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue)

please modify your codes like link example.